# Elasticsearch Cross Cluster Replication (CCR) on Amazon AWS and MS Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, elasticsearch, deployment, cloud

I am wondering if there is a support for [elastic search cross cluster replication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-ccr.html) on AWS and Azure?
I see [AWS announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/06/announcing-cross-cluster-search-support-for-amazon-elasticsearch-service/) where said that they are going to support cross cluster search (don't sure that is tis related to my query though).

Could you please advice if it is supported or are there any news pointing that it might be supported in the nearest future?

Highly appreciate any help.

Comment: you should ask elastic developers in github.

Comment: Elasticsearch Service support cross-zone replication. If you enable replicas for your Elasticsearch indices and use multiple Availability Zones, Amazon Elasticsearch Service automatically distributes your primary and replica shards across instances in different AZs.

Comment: Ok, but this is not what I asked. In this case it is not two clusters, it is one distributed cluster. I asked about CCR actually.
CCR is for replicated data across two completely distinct clusters. This is in contrast to an HA setup within a single cluster where rack-aware nodes are spread across availability zones.

Comment: @liotur have you got the answer? I also looking whether AWS provide elasticsearch with cross cluster replication feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last Amazon releases new opensearch service for elasticsearch cross cluster replication. Here is announce - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/10/amazon-opensearch-service-amazon-elasticsearch-service-cross-cluster-replication/

Answer (score 0):

AWS Elasticsearch doesn't have CCR(Cross Cluster Replication).
However you can achieve (depends on your RTO & RPO) the same by taking manual snapshots into your own S3 there by replicating the data into new Domain.

For more info on manual snapshots , you can go through [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html)